# Switching the java version in MATLAB on OS X 10.8

Tags: java, macos, matlab

I have already set my MATLAB_JAVA variable as explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1812J/) 
and my system says java version 1.7.0_25 when I type `java -version` however, when I go to MATLAB and type `version -java` it says `Java 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode`.  How do I get it so that it sees Java 1.7 in Mountain Lion 10.8?

Comment: From that article "
Note1: On the Mac platform the MATLAB_JAVA environment variable cannot be used to modify the JVM that is being used by MATLAB. "

Comment: Switching between Java versions on OS X used to be easy. Not any more. Are you trying to fix one Matlab's recent major Java bugs or just trying to use 1.7? I believe that Matlab on OS X uses the system JRE. How did you install 1.7? I think that Oracle installs it alongside 1.6 rather than replacing/updating 1.6, which is the problem. Maybe see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/490425/) or [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69086/) or [this](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57539151-263/) or similar. No idea if Matlab will recognize 1.7 at that point though.

Comment: Thank you Mark and horchler. I'm sorry that I didn't see that earlier, and for have wasting your time.  I need to use Java 1.7 as this one specific toolbox I'm trying to use needs it.  I installed 1.7 by using the installer, and its installed in directory `/Users/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/jdk...`

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed with newer releases of Matlab. R2013a, which it looks like you were running, was stuck with the Apple-distributed 1.6 JVM on OS X. Starting with R2013b, Matlab on OS X ships with a bundled JVM like it does on other platforms, and MATLAB_JAVA works now. And the bundled JVM is 1.7. So this issue can be fixed by upgrading to R2013b or later.